# Using an if statement with a let/const statement, without a block statement

Tags: javascript, if-statement, syntax, ecmascript-6

In JavaScript, I can declare a variable using `var` in an `if` statement, without a block statement:

```
if (true)
  var theAnswer = 42
```

However, trying to declare a variable using `let` or `const` without a block statement gives an error:

```js
if (true)
  let theAnswer = 42
```

Chrome throws `SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier`, Firefox—`SyntaxError: lexical declaration not directly within block`.

```js
if (true)
  const theAnswer = 42
```

Here Chrome throws `SyntaxError: Unexpected token const`, Firefox—`SyntaxError: const declaration not directly within block`.

What is the reason of that? Is there anything in the specification that would explain this behavior?

Comment: What would `if (false) let val = 4; console.log(val);` print? It would never have been declared, so it would always throw an exception.

Comment: @loganfsmyth I'm not sure what you're trying to say. I would expect this code to throw a `ReferenceError`, not a `SyntaxError`. However `if (false) var val = 4; console.log(val)` doesn't throw any errors; instead, it logs `undefined` (due to variable hoisting).

Comment: @Gothdo well consider it a bit - `if (cond) let a = 1;` can NEVER do anything and is effectively dead code, then why would you want a ReferenceError? The JS interpreter already knows it's useless and that you literally can't do anything with it, so I find it entirely sensible to get an error. Such a statement can only be written wrongly, after all. Sure, you can have other language constructs that result in no effect but this specific one is 1. new, so it can be more rigorously enforced 2. trivial to check for validity.

Comment: @vlaz But why couldn't `if (cond) let a = 1;` make the `a` variable scoped to the parent block?

Comment: @Gothdo because it's not how `let` works. If you want it there, then declare it in the parent block.

Answer (score 0):

It would be a foot-gun with little to gain. `var` initialization is hoisted, so the variable is guaranteed to always exist inside the function and always have a value. `let` and `const` are scoped within blocks/functions and initialization is not hoisted. What this means is that if the case you present was allowed, code like the following would throw:

```
if (false) let foo = 4;

console.log(foo);
```

Because the `let foo` line never executes, the `foo` variable would never be initialized. That means that accessing the `foo` variable would always trigger a "temporal dead zone" error, just like

```
console.log(foo);
let foo = 4;
```

would.

By disallowing `let` without a direct block/function wrapper, `let` would be dangerous and provide minimal gain.

Comment: So is there a special reason to throw the error in question? It seems as if there are already sufficient rules to govern the situation

Comment: @aw04 it's completely meaningless code _at best_ dangerous and error prone in most other circumstances. Is there a special reason _not_ to throw an error about a situation that can either come back and bite you or (again) _at best_ means you have written a piece of dead code?

Comment: Why do you need a special reason not to throw an error? I was curious about the special reason why the error is thrown. The point being that if it just gave a reference error on the next line, that seems like expected behavior.

Comment: I agree that it's meaningless, but javascript allows you to do alot of meaningless things... as do most programming languages if you don't understand the rules

Comment: to answer my own question, it's the duplicate target answer

Comment: @aw04 as you said yourself, you'll get a Reference error on the next line. Unless it's not the next line but 10 lines down. Or 20. Or 200. Whatever the case you will ALWAYS get a ReferenceError. The only way the code does not cause a problem is if it's never used after the fact, ever, in which case, you have no reason for having it. Considering the _rest_ of the JS syntax, it's not entirely clear for all developers why `if(cond) let val = 7;` could not be referenced - every other thing (aside from `const`) would work - `if (cond) function f()` or `if (cond) var val = 7` would not throw if used

Comment: It would be quite easy to see that and assume it behaved like `var` for instance and that it would initialize to `undefined` or something. It's not always going to be a problem, but it's a much better experience to just avoid allowing it in the language.

Comment: A situation where the variable would not be useless: `let server = app.listen(() => console.log(server.address()))`. Yes this works (until you try to use it with a single-line `if`).